# Jquery Tabs Help

Tags: jquery, css, xhtml, tabs

So I am trying to make a tabs in a menu but cant make the whole width of each of the tabs 219px. it only allows me to make the li 219 but I wanna make the li a 219px. I cant seem to figure it out. Also is there a way to make a next button or would the best way to go to each tab and literally put in the next tab in a  type of way?

any help would be greatly appreciated

Css

```
.servicesNavigation li {
    float: left;
    list-style: none;
    width: 219px;
}

ul.servicesNavigation li a {
    padding: 3px 5px;
    background-color: #ccc;
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
    width: 219px;
}

ul.servicesNavigation li a.selected, ul.tabNavigation li a:hover {
    background-color: #333;
    color: #fff;
    padding-top: 7px;
}

ul.servicesNavigation li a:focus {
    outline: 0;
}
```

HTML

```
<ul class="servicesNavigation">
<li><a href="#Web">Web</a></li>
<li><a href="#Print">Print</a></li>
<li><a href="#DynamicContent">Dynamic Content</a></li>
<li><a href="#Hosting">Hosting</a></li>
</ul>
```

Jquery

```
var tabContainers = $('div.servicesInfo > div');
tabContainers.hide().filter(':first').show();

$('div.servicesInfo ul.servicesNavigation a').click(function () {
    tabContainers.hide();
    tabContainers.filter(this.hash).show();
    $('div.servicesInfo ul.servicesNavigation a').removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');
    return false;
}).filter(':first').click();
```

Answer (score 2):

### Width of Anchor

Anchors are by default displayed as `inline` elements. An `inline` element will only be given the minimum amount of height and width necessary to display its contents.

You could declare that they should be displayed as `block` elements. This way, the browser will honor the `width` declaration you have provided.

To then prevent your links from overflowing out the right of your list elements by 10px, remove the width specification for the `li`.

```
.servicesNavigation li {
    float: left;
    list-style: none;
    /* width: 219px; */ <-- Remove this declaration
}

ul.servicesNavigation li a {
    display: block; <-- Add this declaration
    padding: 3px 5px;
    background-color: #ccc;
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
    width: 219px;
}
```

### Next/Previous

I would suggest adding the following tags somewhere outside of your list, styled any way you'd like:

```
<a id="previous" href="#previous">previous</a>
<a id="next" href="#next">next</a>
```

Then you can easily bind a handler to the `click` event of each to find the link corresponding with the new tab to display and in turn trigger *its* `click` event.

```
$('#next').click(function() {
   var selectedLink = 
      $('div.servicesInfo ul.servicesNavigation a.selected').first();
   selectedLink.parent().next().children().click();
   return false;
});

$('#previous').click(function() {
   var selectedLink = 
      $('div.servicesInfo ul.servicesNavigation a.selected').first();
   selectedLink.parent().prev().children().click();
   return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot set a width to inline elements. Try `li a {display:inline-block;}`